# Access database from another server is not working SQL(Putty)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to database from another server, But It doesn't seem to work
I have used

```
grant all on root.* to 'linked'@'IPADDRESSOFOTHER SERVER' identified by 'password'
```

Comment: What sort of error message are you getting? Are you sure MySQL is the problem, or is the connection being blocked before even reaching that point? Could be a firewall, for example.

Comment: I have allowed firewalls through that port

Comment: and there are no error messages, it asks me to log in and doesn't display anything

Answer (score 0):

```
grant all on root.*  to 'linked'@ . . .
```

That will grant the user named `linked` privileges to access only tables in a database named `root`.

Is the name of your database `root`? Okay, from your comment you confirm that this is the name of the database. That's unusual, but it shouldn't do any harm.

---

The method I would use to test is to open a shell window on your OTHER SERVER, the one you are intending to initiate connections from. We'll call this the *client host*.

Run the mysql client to connect:

```
$ mysql --host=DBSERVER --user=linked --password root
Enter Password:
```

Where DBSERVER is the hostname or IP address of the server where the MySQL is running.

The client pauses, waiting for you to type your password. It will not echo what you type, for security reasons. Then you hit return.

It should either give an error message, or else let you in and give you a `mysql>` prompt.

Comment: Yes database is called root